# How to change the background colour of button when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to `reactjs` and `javascript`. I have list of buttons from A to Z when I click on alphabet the background colour of button should change. I tried below code

```
getBrandSortData(){
    return(
        <div className="BrandPageList_AlphabetContainer">
            <button value="all" className="BrandPageList_AllButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>All</button>
            {brandList.map((item,index) => 
            {
                let disbaled = !this.isBrandCharacterAvailable(item)
                return(
                    <button 
                    disabled= {disbaled}
                    value={item} 
                    key={index} 
                    block="BrandPageList_AlphabetButtons"
                    // mods = {{enabled : !disbaled}}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                {item}
                </button>
            )}
                
            )}
        </div>
    )
}


handleClick = event =>{
    const brandValues = event.target.value
    if(brandValues === "all"){
        brandValues.style.backgroundColor = '#393939'
        return this.setAllBrands()
    }
    else{
        let brandSortDataByCharacter = this.state.brandSortData[brandValues]
       this.setState({
           allBrands:
               {
                   [brandValues]: brandSortDataByCharacter
               },
       })
    }
}
```

I am not able to change the background colour. How to solve this. The above code is written inside a component.

Comment: `event.target` refers to the element itself. `event.target.value` refers to its [`value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value). You should be able to figure out where you've gone wrong from that

Comment: you can also do it using `state` or `useRef` hook

Comment: @kunalpanchal How to do it with state

Answer (score 2):

Update your `handleClick` event handler

```js
handleClick = event =>{
    const brand = event.target;
    if(brand.value === "all"){
        brand.style.backgroundColor = '#393939'
        return this.setAllBrands()
    }
    else{
        let brandSortDataByCharacter = this.state.brandSortData[brand.value]
       this.setState({
           allBrands:
               {
                   [brand.value]: brandSortDataByCharacter
               },
       })
    }
}
```

`event.target` contains the style object.

Comment: I tried adding the `const brand = event.target;`  but the filter wont happen because `brand` variable is holding the value of the button i click to sort the data

Answer (score 0):

For React Js;

```
  var Button = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          bgColor: 'red'
        }
        
      },
      
      handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({
          bgColor: 'blue'
        })
      },
      
      render : function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button 
              onClick={this.handleClick} 
              style={{backgroundColor:this.state.bgColor}}>Button</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    });
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Button />,
        document.getElementById('button')
    );
    `
```

For React Native it is so simple using Usestate.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const Press1 = () => setActive(!active);

  const buttonTextStyle = {
    backgroundColor: active ? 'green' : 'red',
  };
```

No need of using Button in React Native, Just create ur own customizable buttons using Views and TouchableOpacity.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{width: '50%'}} onPress={Press1}>
        <View style={buttonTextStyle}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'white'}}>
            Press Me
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hope It will work.

Comment: I tried the `reactjs` code but if I click any button it applies for all the buttons